# Need a macro to filter latest date in a row

Tags: excel, vba

Can you please help me with a macro which identies and filters automatically a row with the Latest date or row of data updated with the latest date (not necessary to be today's date) in a sheet.

```
Dim dDate As Date

Dim strDate As String

Dim lDate As Long

dDate = [Today()]

'dDate = DateSerial(2017, 2, 28)

lDate = dDate

Range("A1").AutoFilter

Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=">=" & lDate, _
    Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<" & lDate + 1
```

Comment: I'm sorry that I have to tell you that StackOverflow is not a free code writing service. You will need to show the code you have a specific problem with to gain any help here. You can't just write I need this or that and let other people do your work. Getting help doesn't mean that anyone does it for you it means that you need to show where you got stuck.

Comment: This is what I have tried but this provides me the date as of today. But i require the lates date the team would have updated, say they might even last updated the data on 2nd March which is my latest date

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean with "the lates date the team would have updated"? You will need to explain that.

Comment: Need assistance in filtering the Date row which has dates say from 1st Jan 2016 till 5th March 2017. Macro should filter the last updated date which is 5th march 2017 and every week this macro will be run and shlould fetch only the latest date

Comment: Still not sure what you are trying to get. Do you just want to get the most recent date of a column full of dates?

Comment: yes. exactly thats the requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question you should have asked was something like: "How do I find the most recent date out of a column full of dates."

Here is the solution for that question:

```
Dim Max_date as Date
Max_date = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Columns("X"))
```

Where X is the column containing the dates.